# Ruby exits my each loop when an if-statement inside is false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Why does code below exit the each loop as soon as the if-statement "g2k.has_key?(k)" is *false*

```
  e.element_children.all? do |n|
    k = n.name.to_sym
    logger.info("#{n.name} as symbol is '#{k}' is valid? = #{g2k.has_key?(k)}")
    if g2k.has_key?(k)
      logger.info("#{g2k[k] }= #{n.content}")
    #  @vehicle_data[g2k[k]] = n.content
    end
  end
```

This loops through all element children as intended

```
  e.element_children.all? do |n|
    k = n.name.to_sym
    logger.info("#{n.name} as symbol is '#{k}' is valid? = #{g2k.has_key?(k)}")
    #if g2k.has_key?(k)
    #  logger.info("#{g2k[k] }= #{n.content}")
    #  @vehicle_data[g2k[k]] = n.content
    #end
  end
```

I'm using rails 3.2 with Ruy 1.9, parsing XML with nokogiri.

Comment: What happens if you keep the lines `if ...` and `end` but comment out just the one line that starts with `logger.info(...)`?

Comment: Isn't all? for checking if all elements meet a condition? As soon as it's false, why do the rest? An if statement returns a value, as does log... Likely short-circuiting, scruff I can't check the source at the moment.

Comment: In the title you mention an `each` loop, which would do what you want. Your code uses an `all?` method - note the question mark in the methodname.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once `all?` finds something false, then it can't be all, so it's going to stop processing.

Here's an example: http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/cb777 --- you'll see that it stops after printing 5 because 5 is not < 5

```
(1..20).all? do |i|
  puts i
  i < 5
end

# prints:
1 
2 
3 
4 
5
```

Comment: Hmmmm - that makes sense! And with an each it work as I want it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are capturing the output of the .all? method you should not be using it.  .all? is used to make sure every element in an array returns true.  .each will just iterate over all of them.  .detect will iterate until true is returned.

Comment: This is what I did! I changed it to an `each`.